# Finding the Total transactions done by an user in each month

Tags: sql, transactions

There is a user `table(usr)` and a `transactions(txn) table` .The transactions table contains the following fields :- `Usr_id, tscn_id,tscn_amt,tscn,date.`

I am not able to write the SQL query to find the total transaction amount for each user calculated for each month. Could someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
SELECT 
    sum(tscn_amt) as total,
    Usr_id,to_char(date,'MM') as month 
FROM txn 
GROUP BY Usr_id, to_char(date,'MM');
```

Comment: Thanks smn_onrocks . It helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
 select sum(tscn_amt) as sum,Usr_id,month(date) from `txn` group by Usr_id, month(date)
```

Check out the [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) in MySQL.